# Use sub-directory if URL includes specific string

Tags: 7, uri, .htaccess

I am using Drupal 7. Right now, I would like to install WordPress in a sub-directory for maintaining my content page. Since I've used my website for a while, I don't want to change my URL for SEO purpose.

What I did right now:

1. Drupal root is in `/var/www/html` folder
2. Created a subfolder under `/var/www/html`
3. Install Wordpress in `/var/www/html/subfolder`

My current blog page's URL is `http://www.example.com/subfolder/my-blog-1.blog.html`.

But my expected blog page's URL is `http://www.example.com/my-blog-1.blog.html`.

How can I avoid using `http://www.example.com/**subfolder**/my-blog-1.blog.html` for my blog?

Is there anything I need to do in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Question is not clear, you want to replace Drupal site with Wordpress?

Comment: @Ziftman Only for blogs. So, I created a subfolder under /var/www/html folder. But I would like to use "http://www.website.com/blog-1.blog.html" instead of using "http://www.website.com/subfolder/blog-1.blog.html"

Comment: and you have Drupal installed under /var/www/html ?

Comment: @Ziftman Yes. I have a Drupal 7 under /var/www/html

Comment: I think (Not sure)  you cant do that, Drupal won't understands if the request for it or for the subdirectory unless you have fixed prefix for WordPress URL which you can exclude from drupal htaccess. see this for Drupal part https://www.drupal.org/node/30334 and this for WordPress part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564881/htaccess-to-rewrite-wordpress-subdirectory-with-permalinks-to-root